# sleep_for causes buffering effect

Tags: c++, multithreading

If I comment out the sleep_for, the program churns out commas and dots without issues. But when I add the sleep_for, it hangs for a while before suddenly writing all of the commas and dots you would have expected to come evenly during the hang all in one go.

This program was reduced to a minimum working example from something that was much larger and more complex, but fortunately the issue remains.

(Compiled using apt-installed g++ 11.2.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS)

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <RingBuffer.h>
#include <thread>

void writeCharToBuffer(volatile bool& quit, char, std::chrono::milliseconds);

int main()
{
    bool quit { false };

    using namespace std::literals;

    std::thread dotToBufferThread { writeCharToBuffer, std::ref(quit), '.', 100ms};
    std::thread commaToBufferThread { writeCharToBuffer, std::ref(quit), ',', 200ms};

    int quitKey;
    std::cin >> quitKey;
    quit = true;

    dotToBufferThread.join();
    commaToBufferThread.join();
}

void writeCharToBuffer(volatile bool& quit, char c, std::chrono::milliseconds d)
{
    while (!quit)
    {
        std::cout << c;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mixing C++11+ with `volatile` in multithreading code is _disgusting_.

Comment: Regarding `volatile`, it's not a thread synchronization keyword.

Comment: Tried your example on windows with gcc & msvc and I don't see anything unusual in the output cadence.

Comment: I'll grant you that - especially after watching JF Bastien's excellent talk at cppcon19 only yesterday. I forgot to remove `volatile` from my minimum working example. It's a relic from some of the stuff I was trying when facing this issue.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Can you add your comment as an answer to allow me to credit you with the answer. How embarrassing of me...lol

Comment: Buffering or not, `std::this_thread::sleep_for` shouldn't impact it. So you either have one or another behavior in both cases.

Comment: @ixSci It impacts it in the sense that it hides the issue by filling buffer so fast that it isn't noticable as the answer points out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output to `std::cout` *is* buffered.

It might be that the output without the delay will fill up the buffer quick enough that you won't notice it.

If you want immediate output you need to explicitly flush it:

```
std::cout << c << std::flush;
```